# how should i get my gps detection get going..?

Tags: android, android-layout, salesforce, android-service

i have created a togglebutton on checking which i want my MyServices Class to start its service...
my main layout file has 3 buttons and on clicking 2nd button my UserStatus activity is started and the toggle on this activity has startService() which i think starts the MyService as the toasts i gave in in between are displayed.Now i intend to do geolocation detection in background but i don't know why the geolocation is not happening,i did it using a video from youtube

---

This is UserStatus activity

```
package com.salesforce.samples.templateapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.location.*;
import android.content.Intent;
public class UserStatus extends Activity {

    ToggleButton statusToggle;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_user_status, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_status);
        statusToggle=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        statusToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked)
                {
                    statusToggle.setTextOn("On");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toggle is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyServices.class));
                }
                else
                {
                    statusToggle.setTextOff("Off");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toggle is off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyServices.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }


    }
```

---

This is MyServices class

```
package com.salesforce.samples.templateapp;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import com.salesforce.androidsdk.app.ForceApp;
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestClient;
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestRequest;
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestResponse;
import com.salesforce.androidsdk.rest.RestClient.AsyncRequestCallback;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyServices extends Service {
    RestClient client;
    double plat;
    double plong;
    int Two_Min=5*60*1000;

    // TextView infoText;

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updation has started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        detectLocation();
        return START_STICKY;

    }

    private void detectLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside detectlocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        LocationManager lm1 = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll1 = new MyLocationListetner();
        Log.v("X",
                "Response:After creating lm and ll ");

        lm1.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, Two_Min, ll1);
        Log.v("X",
                "Response:After lm1.requestLocationUpdates ");
        ll1.onLocationChanged(null);
    }

    class MyLocationListetner implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("X","Response:inside onLocationChanged ");
            Log.v("X","Response:"+location);
            if (location == null) {
                plat = location.getLatitude();
                plong = location.getLongitude();
                Log.v("X",
                        "Response:Location " + Double.toString(plat)+Double.toString(plong));

                String objectType = "akshayg__User__c";
                String objectId = "a02900000089fK3";
                HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                fields.put("Name", "Ashish");
                // fields.put("akshayg__Donor_Location__Latitude__s",
                // Double.toString(plat));
                // fields.put("akshayg__Donor_Location__Longitude__s",
                // Double.toString(plong));
                RestRequest request = null;

                try {
                    request = RestRequest.getRequestForUpdate(
                            getString(R.string.api_version), objectType,
                            objectId, fields);
                    // Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updation has started",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // printHeader("Could not build update request");
                    printException(e);
                    return;
                }

                client.sendAsync(request, new AsyncRequestCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(RestRequest request,
                            RestResponse result) {

                        // Toast.makeText(this,
                        // ""+Double.toString(plat)+","+Double.toString(plong),
                        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        try {
                             //Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            Log.v("X",
                                    "Response: " + result.toString());
                            /*JSONArray records = result.asJSONObject()
                                    .getJSONArray("records");
                            for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++) {
                                // listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"));
                                // listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("akshayg__Phone_Number__c"));
                                // listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("akshayg__Donor_Location__Latitude__s"));
                                // listAdapter.add(records.getJSONObject(i).getString("akshayg__Donor_Location__Longitude__s"));
                            }*/
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            onError(e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception exception) {
                        Log.v("X",
                                "Response: " + exception.toString());

                        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        // MainActivity.this.getString(ForceApp.APP.getSalesforceR().stringGenericError(),
                        // exception.toString()),
                        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });
            }

        }

        private void printException(Exception e) {
            String err = "Error: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location Updation has stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

here is my log cat errors m getting..

```
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.salesforce.samples.templateapp.MyServices@413c8878 with Intent { cmp=com.salesforce.samples.templateapp/.MyServices }: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2403)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1221)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:877)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at com.salesforce.samples.templateapp.MyServices.onStartCommand(MyServices.java:43)
04-02 23:01:33.375: E/AndroidRuntime(4779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2386)
```

the control going till after onLocationChanged() but not entering the if...else condition.
is it bcoz m sending NULL from service class to onLocationChanged()..?
but even if i check location!=null in if condition the control still doesn't go pass the if statement..
please give suggest corrections...!!

Comment: post your logcat errors

Comment: i tried to catch logcat errors but according to my changed problem its not giving any error m only getting some debug and information... now, probblem has slightly changed but still related to services in sndroid so give it another read and let me know where i hvave gone wrong...

Answer (score 0):

As Abhijit said, it would be easier to help you with your LogCat error, because the error you gave is the one that is always displayed by android, for any exception raised in your code.

If I had to guess, I would say that maybe your `UserStatus` activity is not declared in your manifest.

EDIT:
By the way, make sure the GPS is enabled on the device you test on. You might want to verify it programatically in the way they do it on Android developers website, and open the location settings if it is not enabled. Check it out [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html#TaskVerifyProvider).

Comment: thank you for ur efforts but now m using a toggle button instead of switch and as i hv stated in my problem, m getting toasts that the service has started but geolocation detection isnt happening.. and when i try to put a toast inside the detectlocation method it give me error: The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (MyServices.myLocationListetner, 
 String, int)

Comment: Which of your toasts are actually displaying? The error you get is probably in your listener, not in the `detectLocation()` method of your service, right? For this error, you can just use `MyServices.this` instead of `this`.

Comment: i have placed toasts ay various points to monitor the progarm flow. if u hv observd carefully in my code i hv given toast for:
1. "toggle is on" when i click toggle button
2. "Location detection has started" when in onStartCommand() of MyService 
3. "inside detectlocation()" when inside my method to detect location
4. "Location detection has stopped" when in onDestroy()
5. "Toggle is off" when its switched off
so i know its going inside myService class methods but i dont know y its not detecting location..

Comment: I know where your toasts are, I was asking which of them were actually displaying. According to your answer, I imagine all of them show up. If you had logs instead, and post your logcat, we could have saved this time. You didn't tell me if you have checked that the GPS is enabled, I guess you did. Is the method `onLocationChanged()` called in your listener? Even if you don't know why the location is not detected, you could at least track where the problem is, by putting debug logs everywhere (including the listener) to see what is called.

Comment: yes,all the toasts are showing up. GPS is being enabled. and yes onLocationChanged() method is implemented one thing m not sure of is my flow code, when i click toggle button the control is going to onStartCommand() then to detectlocation() now, is my code after onLocationChanged() getting executed... m not familiar with logging errors so cudnt do wat u asked, sry for that..

Comment: hey Joffrey, i logged the errors but turns out the control is not reaching to mylocationlistener() at all...pls suggest how can i over come this...